# How can I resize the current window using a keybind?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I am using Xubuntu desktop, I want to use a keybind (application shortcuts in settings) to activate a command to resize the **current** window to a predetermined size.

For example: `wmctrl -r Firefox -e 1,-1,-1,1000,600`
resizes any an active firefox window to 1000x600.

The problem is it only works for Firefox, I want to do it to the currently active window (by which I mean the window that has focus).

I know `xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname` gives me the current window

but `wmctrl -r xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname -e 1,-1,-1,1000,600` does nothing.

Is there anyway to do this? My guess is maybe I have to use a pipe but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Code (from posts #6 and #8 in [Use wmctrl to unmaximize a window - not toggle](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566045):

```
#!/bin/sh

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_horz
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 1,510,21,510,700
```

The first two `wmctrl` lines are needed for use on active windows which are maximized.

You can choose values for the third line according to your needs.

- Save the code as `resize.sh` in `~/bin`.
- Open `~/bin` in Thunar, the file manager, and change the properties of `resize.sh` by ticking `Allow this file to run as a program`.
- Add the `bin` folder to `$PATH` using `sudo -H mousepad /etc/environment` to insert `/home/your_login_name/bin:` at the beginning of `$PATH`.
- My path is this: `PATH="/home/dkbose/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"` where **dkbose** is my user name (aka login name) which you should change to yours. Note the `:` which is used after each path except the last one and the presence of double quotes.
- Running `. /etc/environment` made the change [take effect immediately](https://askubuntu.com/a/170240/248158).
- You can assign an available keyboard shortcut of your choice to run `resize.sh`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused on the second part. After adding resize.sh to /bin/, what do I do? 

etc/environment starts with:
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/us...

where do I add /home/my_login_name/bin?

Comment: Note that I suggest creating a `bin` folder in your /home directory (that's what `~/bin` means), not in the system itself! It's usually not advisable to add stuff to `/bin` which is very different than `~/bin`. Please see the edited answer for the `PATH` stuff. All the best.

Comment: Code changed to deal with maximized windows.

Comment: Thanks, I did the following and it makes more sense. but I get the following error when I tried to run it: bash: /home/shamthosh/bin/resize.sh: Permission denied
. If I run as sudo, then I get: sudo: resize.sh: command not found.

Comment: You need to make the script executable. Answer has been edited. No need for sudo.